# При возведении в куб некоторых положительных чисел получается отрицательное число

Tags: c#

Почему при возведении некоторых положительных чисел в куб получается отрицательное число? Например 9630 или 2750

```cs
int num = 9630;
int cube = num * num * num;
Console.WriteLine(cube);
// вывод -296850568
```

Comment: Переполнение `int`. `Int32` (он же `int`) имеет максимальное значение 2147483647. 9630^3 = 893056347000. Используйте `decimal` или `Int64`.

Comment: Если даже разрядности long и decimal окажется мало, используйте [BigIntiger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 8):

Число 9630 в кубе это 893 056 347 000. А, т.к. [int](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int) имеет диапазон От -2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647 естественно результат некорректный (переполнение).

Используйте [long](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/long) или [decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) вместо int для таких чисел.